# Umbraco - property as collection of IPublishedContent

Tags: razor, umbraco, umbraco7

I am working with an umbraco document type which has a collection of IPublishedContent as a property. This manifests itself in the view as a string which is a CSV of the keys of the objects, which I then have to parse and look up the underlying values using the content helper.

```
 by @foreach (var author in Umbraco.Content(story.GetPropertyValue<string>("author").Split(',')))
   {
      @author.Name 
   }
```

As an MVC developer, this feels very wrong. Is there a better way that I am missing? Ideally Umbraco should know that these are actually content items and map them, similar to a navigation property in an ORM.

Would be happy to go with a strongly typed approach, but I cant find much documentation other than to break everything into child actions.

Comment: This is also the way I do this, there might be something in the umbraco helpers. But at the end of the day, the stored data is actually just a CSV of ids. But it would be very nice if we could GetPropertyValue<List<IPublishedContent>>("author")!

Answer (score 0):

As an MVC developer you should look at the [Property Editor Value Converters (documentation)](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/extending-umbraco/property-editors/value-converters-v6) which allow you to do a `story.GetPropertyValue<List<IPublishedContent>>("myAlias")`

The .GetPropertyValue<>() method will use the appropriate value converter.

If you are working with v7 they are called "Property Value Converters", but work the same way.

Make sure, if developing a value converter to use the ContentCache (and not relying on uQuery or Services because these trigger database queries).

Comment: Link is broken. This might help [Property Value Converters](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/extending/property-editors/value-converters)